# Find text between html tags and put it in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the text between html tags e.g.:

```
<div id="text">
This is the text I want to put into a variable for later use.
</div>
```

This is what I want to do with the variable:

```
var = ????thedivtext????;

$(function(){
$("#text").val(thedivtext);
)}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var text = $("#text").text();` will give you the text.

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry for the stupid question, now I see the answer.. lol

Answer (score 2):

You need **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** function of jquery, text method does not give html tags if you require then use [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Ny5e5/)**

```
var v = $("#text").text();
```